# What does error code 709 mean when we call Yodlee's getSiteRefreshInfo?

Tags: yodlee

We are getting this error with two users and we cannot find any information about it in the Yodlee documentation.

```
{"siteRefreshStatus":{"siteRefreshStatusId":3,"siteRefreshStatus":"LOGIN_FAILURE"},"siteRefreshMode":{"refreshModeId":1,"refreshMode":"MFA"},"updateInitTime":0,"nextUpdate":2035690865,"code":709,"noOfRetry":0}
```

Are there any other undocumented errors that we should look for?

Answer (score 0):

The 709 is a very rare error and thrown when there is data agent script failure due to unexpected login form fields or wrong values of. Example -  maxlength mismatch.when you are setting more than allowed.

So please make sure you pass all the values of the login form correctly.

We have documented all the majorly used error codes but we will definitely add more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is happening when we are refreshing the account, we are not sending new information. When do you think the new documentation will be ready?